# How select the right node when two nodes are overlapping in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

[image]

I draw a circle and convert this circle into path,and cut the bottom node into two nodes.

[image]

I want move the node of rightside,but those two nodes are overlapping,I can't select the right node.

[image]

I just can move the leftside node,but this not what I want to move. Now the question is:

**【 How can I select the right node when two nodes are overlapping? 】**

If those two nodes are belong to two paths,I can move one path upper or lower and select the right node,but when those two nodes are at the same path,how can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

Here are a a couple of workarounds.

Use the Select Paths by Nodes Tool (F2)

1. Click on a section of the path that is next to the node you want to move. This will select the two nodes for that section. Although you might not be able to see both are selected, they are.
2. Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click on the node you don't want to move. This will deselect it. The other node will still be selected (although again, you may not be able to see this).
3. Use the arrow keys on your keyboard to move the node away from the other that is overlapping it, then you can grab it and move it as normal.

Example

[image]

Another possible solution is to click *Object > Flip Horizontal* before selecting the node. Although this will work for symmetrical shapes, it's obviously not a viable solution for shapes that aren't symmetrical.

Comment: thank you so much to solve my problem in just 48 mins

Answer (score 2):

There's also the option to use Tab to select a different node. So, select the adjacent node, and then use either Tab or Shift+Tab to select the one you actually want to select.

Comment: Much precise and better way! Thank you.